# How to remove a hyperlink from navigation menu

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have installed a custom theme and my navigation menu is as such:
Home | Services | About Us, etc.
Under Services > Page 1 > Page 2, etc.

However, I had to create a page for Services in order to have it my menu. I want to remove the hyperlink to Services while having it in my navigation menu. Is this possible?

Site: http://www.fafunding.com

Answer (score 2):

Yes go to **wp-admin** and then **Appearance > Menus**

Now on the left of the **Menus** page select **links**

Where is says URL enter "**#**" (without "") and enter **Services** where it says **Link Text**

Hope that helped

---

*Don't forget to vote up and select as accepted answer if it is.*